# How to insert value into an array of input using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am generating row of input with arrays.

```
@foreach($msp_temp as $current)
 <td>
 <input type="number" step ="0.01" class="required" name="firstEntry[]" id="firstEntry">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" step ="0.01" class="required" name="secondEntry[]" id="secondEntry">
 </td>
 ...
```

I have a variable set somewhere like:

```
var entrysum = 0
```

I want to insert the variable value (entrysum) inside the [] and increase the variable every loop.

How do I insert entrysum value into firstEntry[], secondEntry[], and increase the variable value by 1 after every loop?

Comment: In each iteration you are making input text with same id

Comment: entysum is javascript variable or php variable >

Comment: what does `$current` does here `@foreach($msp_temp as $current)` ?

Answer (score 0):

*I will assume that as per code, there are always a couple of firstEntry and secondEntry and I understand that you want to update them together with the same value.*

---

First, you get all the input numbers whose name starts with firstEntry and another for secondEntry:

```
var firstEntries = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="firstEntry"]');
var secondEntries = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="secondEntry"]');
```

Second, you iterate all elements and autoincrement the value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstEntries.length; i++) {
  firstEntries[i].value = entrysum; // update firstEntry
  secondEntries[i].value = entrysum; // update secondEntry
  entrysum++; // increment entrysum
}
```

*Note: if entrysum always starts in 0 and increments by 1, you can simply use i from the loop instead.*

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@foreach($msp_temp as $current)
 <td>
 <input type="number" step ="0.01" class="required" name="firstEntry[]" id="firstEntry">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" step ="0.01" class="required" name="secondEntry[]" id="secondEntry">
 </td>
@php
$entrysum++;
@endphp
```

Comment: inputext id will be generate same in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side programming/scripting language. Looks like you are pasting elements from PHP, and `entrysum` is a Javascript variable.

PHP is a server-side programming language. You cannot run Javascript before, or at the same time as PHP.

You can achieve your task by using a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, accessing the elements by index.

If you had this setup:

```
$msp_temp = [];
$i = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($msp_temp); $i++){
    echo "<input type='number' step ='0.01' class='required' name='secondEntry[$i]' id='secondEntry'>";
    // ...
}
echo "<script>var entrysum = $i;</script>"
```

The number will increase automatically, and the variable will be available for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are somewhat confused with `[]` array brackets is automatically increased next key,so

**No need to to put extra effort to make array key**

Rather you need to make input text id unique, to make unique id just add `$key` like this

```
@foreach($msp_temp as $key=>$current)
  <td>
   <input type="number" step ="0.01" class="required" name="firstEntry[]" id="firstEntry{{$key}}">
  </td>
```

Just submit you form and check post request you will get array of `firstEntry` and `secondEntry`